# Detrending a Series in Practice

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares, trend

Say I want to regress a variable $y_t$ on $X_t$ using ordinary least squares, with the inclusion of a constant, when $X_t$ exhibits a deterministic trend.

Let's say I detrend $X_t$ by running a regression on a time index variable and obtain the residuals $(\hat{u}_t)$.

When it is time to regress $y_t$ on $X_t$, do I use $\hat{u}_t$ instead of $X_t$?

For example:

$y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1\hat{u}_t$

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious thing to do would seem to include a time trend in the regression of $y_t$ on $X_t$, i.e.
$$
y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1t+\beta_2X_t+error
$$
Now, by the [Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisch%E2%80%93Waugh%E2%80%93Lovell_theorem), the estimate for $\beta_2$ of that regression will be exactly the same if you

- first regress $y_t$ on a constant and the trend, save the residuals, call them $\hat{u}_{yt}$,
- then regress $X_t$ on a constant and the trend, save the residuals, call them $\hat{u}_{Xt}$,
- and finally regress $\hat{u}_{yt}$ on $\hat{u}_{Xt}$ and take the resulting coefficient.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the first step. The estimate of $\beta_2$ will be the same even if the original dep var is used. So the answer to the question is yes, even without the addition of step one.